# Insert image in moodle quizz using moodle.sty

Tags: includegraphics, moodle

I am trying using the moodle.sty packages and I have question with image.
The problem is that the xml file that is made is not correct for the image (I get " when I look at the html code in Moodle). The image is missing after base64,
My tex file is the following

Thanks in advance for any help

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\graphicspath#1{\def\Ginput@path{#1}\edef\moodleimgpath{\@firstofone#1}}

\xpatchcmd{\moodle@includegraphics@int@int}%
{\openssl\otherspace enc -base64 -in #2.png -out #2.enc}%
{\openssl\otherspace enc -base64 -in \moodleimgpath#2.png -out #2.enc}%
{\typeout{patch ok}}%
{\typeout{patch failed}}
\makeatother

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first quiz}


  \begin{multi}[shuffle=true, points=1]{Newton laws - 1}
    blablabla

    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{figac}

  \item* 1
  \item 2
\end{multi}

\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

Using @Rmano file my output is:

```
macbook-pro-de-christine:Test latex moodle christine.fauvelle-aymar$ lualatex --shell-escape essai.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
 system commands enabled.
(./essai.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /Users/christine.fauvelle-aymar/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic /Users/christine.fauvelle-aymar/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic)sh: all: command not found

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.154 seconds
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(load luc: /Users/
christine.fauvelle-aymar/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fo
nts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moodle/moodle.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty))
uname -s > "essai.w18"

! Package catchfile Error: File `essai.w18' not found.

See the catchfile package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.93     \CatchFileDef\@tempa{\ip@file}{}

? X
 368 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 dir, 3 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list, 4 if_st
ack, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:5,3:3,4:1,5:1,7:2,9:2

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on essai.log.
```

Comment: On which platform are you working?

Comment: I am working with TexShop (mac OS)

Comment: I see that you are using my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539721/moodle-sty-does-not-insert-graphics-in-xml-output-file/. Maybe to find out what the issue exactly is you can leave that part out, so delete everything from `\usepackage{xpatch}` up to and including `\graphicspath{{./figures/}}`, then put the image (`figac.png` or `figac.jpg` or `figac.pdf` whichever it is) in the same folder as the `.tex` file, and then run again. Also take a look at the `log` file and include any relevant parts in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the log file. However, now I am a bit confused: in your question you say that the XML file does not contain the image, but in this log you get an error and no output is produced. So this is not the log file from your original question I think? And it is also not the log file of the simplified version I suggested without the `xpatch` stuff? It would make the question more clear if the log file would actually correspond to the code.

Comment: By the way, if you want to add information to the question or change things to clarify then you can use the small `edit` link just below the question text.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this will depend on the platform where you are working. My experience is with Linux. Basically

1. I do not know why you are modifying internal commands. My Moodle works correctly including images... provided you use the full name (I know, I know, it shouldn't be like that, but...) like `\includegraphics{myfig.pdf}`.
2. The figure must be in the same directory as the main file, although there are patches floating around to fix it.
3. You have to call the interpreter with the `--shell-escape` flag.
4. `lualatex` works better if you have any accented char in your text (well, works, because with `pdflatex` it will not).
5. I got bitten by this [`imagemagick` over-zelous setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453) which was a pain-in-the-back to find...

I hope this helps...

As an example. I had this figure saved as `fullrect.png`:

[image]

and this code in `testquiz.tex`:

```latex
% vim: set spelllang=es :
%! TEX program = lualatex
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{moodle}
\moodleset{ppi=200}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Rectificadores} % Nombre del banco de preguntas

    \begin{multi}{Medida del termopar}

    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{fullrect.png}

    A ver, supon que tienes este circuito arriba.  El valor medio de la tensión a la salida $u_1$ es \dots
        \item*  positivo
        \item  negativo
        \item nulo
    \end{multi}

\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

which I compile with:

```
lualatex --shell-escape testquiz.tex
```

A `testquiz-moodle.xml` file is generated, and it gives:

[image]

And yes, the resolution is low, but I have a trick to enhance it, if you need it you can ask.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work - the pdf file is correct but not the xml

Comment: @ChristineFA I need more info to help you. Try to run the compilation command in a terminal, and put the output in the question.

Comment: I run your file using the terminal but it didn't work. I get

Comment: @Rmano: I would be very interested to know, how one could improve the resolution of the included pictures in the final xml-file. Changing ppi and/or changing width did not help for me.

Comment: @I_M have you tried with a recent moodle.sty? Current version is 0.9 and it's **much** better than last year version, thanks to Matthieu. Have a look at https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle and the current manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/moodle?lang=en. If you still have problems, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and post a new question, we will try to help.